# Fourier transform of a non absolutely integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

How to find the Fourier transform of a non absolutely integrable function? I read several problem books and still don't understand how to do it. For example $\sin((x+a)^2)$

Comment: Have you studied generalized functions, tempereed distributions etc.?

Comment: @kavi-rama-murthy No

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot define FT of this function using just basic Calculus.

Comment: maybe it can be done somehow using a differentiated equation?